# PDO Link function

Tags: php, pdo

im having a hard time constructing code using PDO, my goal is how can i link to another page embedded with the id.

```
    <?php
        foreach ($job_order_data_new as $new_order) {

        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php if(!empty($new_order['date'])) echo $new_order['date'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php if(!empty($new_order['job_title'])) echo $new_order['job_title'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php if(!empty($new_order['requested_by'])) echo $new_order['requested_by'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php if(!empty($new_order['brief'])) echo $new_order['brief'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><?php if(!empty($new_order['priority'])) echo $new_order['priority'], ' '; ?></td>
            <td><a href="">ASSIGN</a>|<a href="">DELETE</a></td>            
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
```

how do i get the id and redirect to another page when user clicks on ASSIGN

Comment: What has this got to do with PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the `!empty()` checks. You should be able to assume, given a successful query and fetch operation, that all selected columns would be present.

Now, assuming...

- the order ID is in `$new_order['id']`
- the *other page* is `assign.php`
- the *other page* is expecting a query variable named `order_id`

how about...

```
<a href="assign.php?order_id=<?= htmlspecialchars($new_order['id']) ?>">ASSIGN</a>
```